# Meaning of \quad

Tags: spacing, typography

Many LaTeX command names have some 'justification'.
For example the commands `\cup` and `\cap` have a straightforward meaning.

However, I couldn't find a meaning for the commands `\quad` and `\qquad`. Is it maybe coming from a concatenation of 'equation' and 'add' ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! “Quad” is a traditional term of typography; it comes from Italian “quadratone” (big square), because it denoted a square piece of metal that could be placed between types for spacing them.

Comment: I had that some doubt, so I wonder if there was a TeX command glossary somewhere. This is what I found:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary

It would be even better if there was an "all-TeX-package command dictionary".

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The word “quad” is a traditional term in typography. It comes from Italian “quadratone” (big square). In old fashioned metal typography it meant a square piece of metal lower than type height that could be inserted between types for spacing them. In Italian typography it's still called “spazio quadratone”.

It's commonly as wide and high as an uppercase “M”, since this is usually the widest letter in a font and occupies a square area.

The command `\quad` takes its name from this traditional name; `\qquad` just means ”two quads”. However in TeX the `\quad` has no height, but only width.

Comment: +1 although I claim you have an unfair advantage when it comes to Italian terms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I’ll start making that comment on posts of yours every time we’re facing an English term `;)`.

Answer (score 42):

Some more information:

QUAD is the abbreviation of [*quadrat*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrat). It comes from [*quadratus* in Latin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrate) (Merriam-Webster).

`\quad` and `\qquad` are macros defined by (La)TeX kernel:

```
\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}
\def\qquad{\hskip2em\relax}
```

For TeXicians, the unit “em” is one of the font dimensions. Say, `\fontdimen6` of a font in TeX. It originally means the width of capital letter M in a font (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)), but it is not always true in practice.

The font dimensions in TeX and the `\fontdimen` command is described in “Appendix F: Font Tables” in *The TeXbook*, and “Appendix F: Font Metric Information” in *The METAFONTbook*.

You can define a macro equivalent to `\quad` like this:

```
\def\myQuad{\hskip\fontdimen6\font}
```

and of course a `\qquad` doubles `\quad`:

```
\def\myQQuad{\hskip2\fontdimen6\font}
```

Comment: And if you want your quads to be flexible, stretchable a little bit so they don’t cause over-long lines, you can define `\def\flexquad{\hskip1em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em\relax}` (change `0.2em` to the amount you find pleasing, of course).

Answer (score 9):

In the Not so Short Intro to LaTex, it says that size of `\quad` corresponds to the width of the character `M` of the current font.

That is, `\qquad` is the space of `MM`.

Comment: does it say that, it's not strictly true, it is the width of 1em which is a notional unit set in the font metrics which may or may not actually be the width of the M in that font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, Section 3.7 Math Spacing doesn't say that.

Comment: @dustin: Do you mean `lshort`? I'm sure that document is not that precise. Frankly speaking I don't think `lshort` is a very good introduction to LaTeX.