# equal distant $\Leftrightarrow$ at each sentence

Tags: pdftex

[image: R]

I want this but when I am writing

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
$$x\in\mathcal{W}_{i+1}\Leftrightarrow \exists y\in\mathcal{W}_i : Ex = Ay = (A-\lambda E)y +\lambda Ey$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \exists y\in\mathcal{W}_i = \ker \hat{E}^i : \hat{E}x = (I + \lambda \hat{E})y =: \hat{y}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \exists \hat{y}\in\ker\hat{E}^i : \hat{E}x = \hat{y}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x\in \ker \hat{E}^ {i+1}$$ .
\end{document}
```

I am getting this

[image]

Comment: You might like to have a quick read of this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to to see why we usually recommend avoiding `$$ ... $$` and using `\[ ... \]` instead. Anyway, you need to use some kind of `align` environment

Comment: `\begin{align*}
x\in\mathcal{W}_{i+1}&\Leftrightarrow \exists ... \\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists y \in ... \\
&\Leftrightarrow ...
...
\end{align*}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the align environment.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}  
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x\in\mathcal{W}_{i+1}&\Longleftrightarrow \exists y\in\mathcal{W}_i : Ex = Ay = (A-\lambda E)y +\lambda Ey\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \exists y\in\mathcal{W}_i = \ker \hat{E}^i : \hat{E}x = (I + \lambda \hat{E})y =: \hat{y}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \exists \hat{y}\in\ker\hat{E}^i : \hat{E}x = \hat{y}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x\in \ker \hat{E}^ {i+1}.\quad  \square
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

I also added the code for a square `\square`

Comment: I was about thirty seconds behind you. +1 Only recommendation is you replace all of those escaped spaces with something like `\quad` or `\qquad`

Comment: @Au101 Good idea, I wasn't aware of ``\quad``. I just edited my answer to include it. Thanks

Comment: Also I was going to suggest using `\Longleftrightarrow` (possibly with a semantically meaningful abbreviation defined as it's rather unwieldy) as it's closer to the symbol in the original. Seems a bit pointless me putting that as a separate answer, but you could include it as a recommendation if you wanted to

Comment: Here you go :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119068/meaning-of-quad

Comment: @Au101 Thanks again. I added the ``\Longleftrightarrow``.

Comment: Any time :) A great way to learn is to have a go at answering and see if you get any suggestions. I've learned plenty from the comments on my own answers, as well as the answers to my questions :)