# What is an entire English sentence for `\qquad`

Tags: white-space, tex-history

An entire English sentence for `\dfrac` might be as follows:

> "insert a display mode fraction"

Note that `dfrac` is a sub-sequence of "insert a **D**isplay mode **FRAC**tion"

What is an entire English sentence for `\qquad` such that the sentence is a subsequence of `qquad`

The meaning is probably something like "insert a white space here"

Comment: "Insert a double quad space, that is, a space of width 2em."

Comment: AFAIK, "quad" wasn't invented by TeX, but taken from traditional typography. M quadrats and N quadrats were metal pieces used to insert whitespace.
So `\quad` means one quad, and `\qquad` means two quads.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_(typography)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from p. 166 of the TeXbook:

> The traditional hot-metal technology has led to some ingrained standards for [certain spacing issues], based on what printers call a "quad" of space. Since these standards seem to work well in practice, TeX makes it easy for you to continue the tradition: When you type `\quad` in plain TeX [and LaTeX], you get a printer's quad of space in the horizontal direction. Similarly, `\qquad` gives you a double quad (twice as much); ...

But where does the term "quad" come from? In modern Dutch and German, and presumably some other Germanic languages as well, a "Quadrat" is a square (noun); "quad", then, is an abbreviation of "Quadrat". The German word "Quadrat", in turn, derives from Latin, and variants of "Quadrat" may thus be found in many modern Romance languages. E.g., one square meter, in modern Italian, is "un metro quadrato".

I don't have a book on the history of movable-type printing in Europe at hand, but I think it's reasonable to assume that the term "quad" would have arisen in the work of printers both north and south of the Alps within a generation or two after the invention of movable type.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119068/4427

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for pointing out the older posting. Indeed, the current posting turns out to be a duplicate of the older posting.