# What is a `\quad`, in plain English?

Tags: spacing, white-space

Thanks to [**this**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119068/meaning-of-quad/119069#119069) excellent answer, we know that *quad* is sub-sequence of a European phrase *spazio quadratone*. However, what is a `\quad` in plain English, for those learning **LaTeX** for the first time?

Comment: "quad" came to English via Latin but is a common English word for "square" (quadrangle) https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/quad